# Standalone executable made with pyinstaller 5.6.2 in Windows 11 throws errors

Tags: python-3.x, windows, pyinstaller

I am using Windows 11 running Anaconda python 3.11.5 and using pyinstaller 5.6.2 to make an executable.
The script runs perfectly when run as a python command,

```
python GrowthRates.py -i ExampleData.in -w 1
```

but when  the resulting .exe file is run  with the command

```
GrowthRates -i ExampleData.in -w 1
```

it returns the the error below:
suggestions?

```
'''
[5500] Module object for pyimod02_importers is NULL!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 22, in <module>
  File "pathlib.py", line 14, in <module>
  File "urllib\parse.py", line 40, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ipaddress'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyiboot01_bootstrap.py", line 17, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyimod02_importers'
[5500] Failed to execute script 'pyiboot01_bootstrap' due to unhandled exception!
'''
```